# PHP printf; Css only works on first row from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, printf

Need Help. I tried to show reader comments on my page. The comments are saved in a database (MySQL). I used `printf(String, args1,args2)` and put some css style on it. Strangely, the css works on the first comment only.

```
if ($conn = mysqli_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname")){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM kommentare ORDER BY datum DESC";
    $ergebnis = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis)){
        **$format = "<p><span id='ueberschrift'>%s<span/>&nbsp;<span id='writer'><a href='mailto:%s'>%s<a/> schrieb am:%s<span/><p/>
             <p id='kommentare'>%s<p/><hr/>";
        printf($format,
               htmlspecialchars($zeile->ueberschrift),     
               urlencode($zeile->email),
               htmlspecialchars($zeile->name),
               htmlspecialchars(date("d.m.Y, H:i", $zeile->datum)),

               nl2br(htmlspecialchars($zeile->kommentar))
              );**
    }
} else {
    echo "Fehler: ".  mysqli_connect_error(). "!";
}
```

```css
#writer{
    font-weight: normal;
    float:right;   
}

 #ueberschrift {
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 14px;
}
```

`float:right` only works on the first comment (last row from database) 
what have I done wrong? Here's an [image of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZAy3.png).

Comment: Use classes to style instead of id

Comment: i tried, but still doesnt work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<span class ='ueberschrift'
<span class ='writer'
```

NOT

```
<span id ='ueberschrift'
<span id='writer'
```

Each id should be unique and only appear once per html document. Class can appear multiple times.

CSS would be:

```
.writer{
    font-weight: normal;
    float:right;   
}

 .ueberschrift {
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 14px;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: i changed everything into classes:

still doesnt work :(

Comment: Try posting the resulting HTML instead of the PHP code.

Comment: try using chrome or firefox inspector on places where you're expecting the formatting and see why the css id or class is not being applied.

Comment: so i put everthing online http://2sigma.ch/index.php well it looks fine for me, except in some line there is "==$0 " at the end of the <span>, i dont realy know what that means. as you can see the float right applied only on the first comment!

Comment: You are closing your p,span and a tags incorrectly  should be </p> not <p/>

Answer (score 0):

Check your html closing tag, **all** your html closing tag is wrong.

Slash `/` is should be put after `<` so its like `</tag>`, except self-closing tag like `<br />` , `<hr />` , etc.

```
<span/> should be </span>
<a/> should be </a>
<p/> sholud be </p>
```

And here the completed of your code

```
if ($conn = mysqli_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password", "$dbname")){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM kommentare ORDER BY datum DESC";
    $ergebnis = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis)){
        **$format = "<p><span id='ueberschrift'>%s</span>&nbsp;<span id='writer'><a href='mailto:%s'>%s</a> schrieb am:%s</span></p>
             <p id='kommentare'>%s</p><hr />";
        printf($format,
               htmlspecialchars($zeile->ueberschrift),     
               urlencode($zeile->email),
               htmlspecialchars($zeile->name),
               htmlspecialchars(date("d.m.Y, H:i", $zeile->datum)),

               nl2br(htmlspecialchars($zeile->kommentar))
              );**
    }
} else {
    echo "Fehler: ".  mysqli_connect_error(). "!";
}
```

it might help you https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#end-tags